# I got Error when installing coocapods from terminal

Tags: ruby, terminal, rubygems, cocoapods

Installing cocoapods from terminal
"ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
There are no versions of cocoapods-downloader (>= 2.0) compatible with your Ruby & RubyGems. Maybe try installing an older version of the gem you're looking for?
cocoapods-downloader requires Ruby version >= 2.7.4. The current ruby version is 2.6.10.210."

I'm using M1 Air, could it be related to that?

Comment: How about updating the Ruby version? It exactly mentions that it requires a higher version of Ruby (>= 2.7.4).

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using the Ruby version built-in to macOS. That's a recipe for disaster since it's ancient and cannot be easily managed if you have multiple Ruby projects with different requirements.

Install [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) and use it to install a newer version of Ruby, then use that to install cocoapods.